# What is the effect of padding zeros to FFT on time domain ? (opposite of what is usually done)

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, signal-analysis, fourier-transform

As above. I know that zero padding in time increasaes frequency resolution but I'm having a hard time to understand the opposite. How would you interpret that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same effect will happen on the time-domain sequence too, due to the fact that DFT time and frequency domains are exact duals apart from a scaling factor and reversal.

Therefore, by properly zero padding (to the center of) the FFT data, the corresponding time-domain signal will be **interpolated**; i.e., more samples from the same signal will be obtained.

Comment: Got it !! so by padding infinitely many zeros, it is like I effectively removed the replicas, invert that padded signal, and you get the continuous version of the signal. I wonder if there's any application for that? I know people pad time signal to increase frequency resolution but not the opposite

Comment: @Fat32 I had a question. Will zero padding in time domain increase the frequency resolution or taking more time domain samples increase the frequency resolution?

Comment: @DSPNovice: this may be worth a separate question. Both will increase the apparent frequency resolution but zero padding simply does interpolation and no new information is gained. Taking more time domain samples adds more data and so there is more information available.

Comment: @AlexDeft padding infinetely many zeros is not a practical operation, but all I can say that the longer you pad the signal, the more samples you interpolate in time which is still a discrete-time sequence by nature. If you want to obtain a continuous-time signal, then you should consider D/C conversion of the samples instead : convert the sequence into impulse train and apply a continuous-time reconstruction lowpass filter... (or practially use a DAC !)

Comment: @DSPNovice frequency resolution (distance between two closest unambigous freq peaks) is only improved by longer observation duration... zero padding, simply interpolates (and hence smooths) the existing envelope, no improvement in the resolution.